# PHPExcel - Convert HTML tag from database efficiently

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to convert content from a column from database to Excel. The column name is 'history'. In the inside of the column 'history', there is HTML tag but only 'br' tag.

I know PHPExcel doesn't build logic to convert HTML tag.

**The problem is there is many data from column 'history' which I want to display in Excel. (There is 3 row which I want to display). But, only 'br' tag in all content in column 'history'. I want to know formula to solve this problem**

Content inside column history in first row

```
salah ketik<br/><br/>(Deleted) 
<br/>Value: IDR 5000<br/>Explanation: beli makan<br/>
<br/>(Edited)
<br/>Value: IDR 10000<
br/>Explanation: beli makan
```

Content inside column history in second row

```
    salah ketik<br/><br/>(Deleted) 
    <br/>Value: IDR 12000<br/>Explanation: beli makan<br/>
    <br/>(Edited)
    <br/>Value: IDR 15000<
    br/>Explanation: beli makan
```

Content inside column history in third row

```
    salah ketik<br/><br/>(Deleted) 
    <br/>Value: IDR 11000<br/>Explanation: beli makan<br/>
    <br/>(Edited)
    <br/>Value: IDR 7000<
    br/>Explanation: beli makan
```

Comment: explain,what u need? How your put content in cell?

Comment: I want to display data from database in Excel using PHPExcel. But there is a HTML tag. And I want to display many data. I want to find formula to solve my problem

Comment: Why not simply `$data = str_replace('<br/>',"\n",$data);` before inserting $data into the PHPExcel cell

Comment: I am unthinkable. Yeah.., true solution. Why not answer this question  ?

Comment: Eh, no no no. Can I replace '<br/>' tag where '<br/>' tag is displayed  from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cell = str_replace(array('<br/>','br/>'),"\n",$content);
$cell = str_replace('<',"",$cell);
```

Comment: oh, I see. This is true answer

Comment: @AndikaK hovever, may be do  `$cell = str_replace('<',"",$content);` after? To remove single sing `<`... Updated answer